# Scrapy - Understanding CrawlSpider and LinkExtractor

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

So I'm trying to use CrawlSpider and understand the following example in the [Scrapy Docs](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

rules = (
    # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
    # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

    # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
    item = scrapy.Item()
    item['id'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
    item['name'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
    item['description'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

The description then given is:

> This spider would start crawling example.com’s home page, collecting category links, and item links, parsing the latter with the parse_item method. For each item response, some data will be extracted from the HTML using XPath, and an Item will be filled with it.

I understand that for the second rule, it extracts links from `item.php` and then extracts the information using the `parse_item` method. However, what exactly is the purpose of the first rule? It just says that it "collects" the links. What does that mean and why is it useful if they are not extracting any data from it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CrawlSpider is very useful when crawling forums searching for posts for example, or categorized online stores when searching for product pages.

The idea is that "somehow" you have to go into each category, searching for links that correspond to product/item information you want to extract. Those product links are the ones specified on the second rule of that example (it says the ones that have `item.php` in the url).

Now how should the spider keep visiting links until finding those containing `item.php`? that's the first rule for. It says to visit every Link containing `category.php` but not `subsection.php`, which means it won't exactly extract any "item" from those links, but it defines the path of the spider to find the real items.

That's why you see it doesn't contain a `callback` method inside the rule, as it won't return that link response for you to process, because it will be directly followed.

Comment: Ah, I see... so this spider would extract data from links that are like `example.com/category.php/item.php`, but not from any links that are like `example.com/subsection.php/item.php`?

Comment: yes, if you mean that to extract `example.com/subsection.php/item.php` it first needs to visit the page `example.com/subsection.php`. Let say you are at `example.com` (home page) and inside that page it has only 2 links (inside the body): `example.com/category.php` and `example.com/subsection.php`, and when you visit them you can find product urls (with `item.php`). Then the spider will only extract those inside `category.php` because it NEVER visited `subsection.php`.

Comment: I see... thanks! So then if there are lets say that there was also a third link `example.com/third.php/item.php` but I had the same rule as above, would it parse these links? Just confused on the behavior because `third.php` would be in neither the `allow=()` or `deny=()`. Do you have to manually deny all possible extra links?

Comment: if the spider finds that `third.php/item.php` link inside `category.php` links, then yes, it would be extracted. It only says that it will visit `category.php` links. It won't visit `category.php/subsection.php` links. Remember that "visited" links are different that "extracted" links.

Comment: hmm... I guess my question is basically, would a link like `example.com/third.php/item.php` be visited by this spider at all?

Comment: again, if that link is found inside `example.com/third.php` (thinking that this is a category) then no. Now "IF" the link was found somehow, this link would be "extracted", so you can process it on `parse_item`. The whole functionality I think is explained in the [`_requests_to_follow` method of CrawlSpider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L56)